# virtuoso-opensource: using jenaprovider, how to read data from file instead of from URL?

Tags: java, rdf, virtuoso

It is pretty simple to load data from an URL using `jena provider` for `virtuoso`. The following code does the job:

```
    VirtGraph graph = new VirtGraph ("foaf", "jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111", "dba", "dba");

/*      Load data to Virtuoso       */

    System.out.print ("Begin read from 'http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/index.rdf'  ");
    graph.read("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/index.rdf", "RDF/XML");
```

However thing are different when you want to load them from a local file. I tried this:

```
    VirtGraph graph = new VirtGraph ("foaf", "jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111", "dba", "dba");

    graph.read("/tmp/index.rdf", "RDF/XML");
    graph.close();
```

But I end up with the following Exception:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: virtuoso.jdbc4.VirtuosoException: HC001: Connection Error in HTTP Client
```

do someone have any clue about how to load rdf from file using jenaprovider ?

**Configuration setting**
virt_jena2.jar
virtjdbc4.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than providing just the filename, use a [file URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) instead. E.g.:

```
graph.read("file:///tmp/index.rdf", "RDF/XML");
```

Answer (score 1):

About your first example:

```
VirtGraph graph = new VirtGraph ("foaf", "jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111", "dba", "dba");
graph.read("http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/index.rdf", "RDF/XML");
```

It is converted to next SPARQL command (that is executed on server side  - [Sources](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/develop/7/binsrc/jena2/virtuoso_driver/VirtGraph.java#L928-L944)):

```
load "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/index.rdf" into graph <foaf>
```

And this command doesn't allow to load your local files to DBMS.
You could use Jena Model methods for load local files. Like the next ([Jena Model reference](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)):

```
  Model model = VirtModel.openDatabaseModel("load:test", "jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111", "dba", "dba");
  InputStream in = FileManager.get().open( nfile );
  if (in == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + nfile + " not found");
  }
  model.read(new InputStreamReader(in), null, "N-TRIPLE");
  model.close();
```

Comment: can you add some links as references in your answer ?